# LMS1XX on ROS Kinetic

Tags: lidar, sicklms, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hy,

I am trying to get a connection in ROS Kinetic to my LMS111 Laserscanner with:

```
 rosrun lms1xx LMS1xx_node _host:=192.168.3.7
```

The result is a connection fail. I saw the other posts like http://answers.ros.org/question/207220/connecting-a-sick-laserscanner-via-ethernet/ and http://answers.ros.org/question/66437/using-the-sicktoolbox_wrapper-with-lms1xx/ bbut there is never a full description to the solution...
Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem or could provide a full solution path?

Thanks in advance,

Michael

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261628/lms1xx-on-ros-kinetic/) by [mtROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/29774/mtros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2017-05-12

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2017-05-14**:
I think the problem is due to permission of the port. Try $ sudo chmod a+rx [port of the LMS]  before launching the lms node. It should work. I have had no problems using LMS sensors on ROS kinetic so far.

**Comment by [mtROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/29774/mtros/) on 2017-05-15**:
i messed up the configuration, thanks for your answer, i added a solution path below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to establish a connection of the Laserscanner SICK LMS111 to ROS Kinetic several steps have to be performed.

1.Supply the Sensor and connect it to the ethernet port a system running Windows.
2. Install SICK SOPAS Engineering tool and execute it.
3. Configure the Paramters in the SICK Software SOPAS. That means define a ethernet ip adress and adjust measuring parameters.
4.Install the sick toolbox wrapper:

> $ sudo apt-get install
> ros-kinetic-lms1xx

5. In Ubuntu under Settings configure the wired connection to be different than the IP of the laserscanner. The IP of the laserscanner can be obtained by

> $ sudo ifconfig

6. Make sure that the connection between ubuntu and the LMS is established in Ubuntu (You can see this in the Network Settings).

> $ roscore

8. In order to establish a connection to ROS use a new terminal and enter

> $ rosrun lms1xx LMS1xx_node _
> host:=[IP of the scanner obtained from
> sudo ifconfig]

has to be used.

9.When using rviz: the fixed frame in global options has to be set to laser and a LaserScan display has to be added with the topic /scan enabled.

---

Originally posted by [mtROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/29774/mtros/) with karma: 92 on 2017-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0